# Testing Vue filters with jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

i'm trying to write a test for one of my filters in my Vue project using jest  , can i Test that filter without using it in any component, i mean can i test it as a unit(like a function)? i searched a lot but i couldn't find anything to show me how to write an individual test for a filter in Vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default function () {
    Vue.filter('englishNumber', (value) => {
        if (value === '۰') return 0
        if (!value) return ''
        if (typeof value !== 'string') {
            value = value.toString()
        }
        return value.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9]+/g, function (digit) {
            let ret = ''
            for (let i = 0, len = digit.length; i < len; i++) {
                ret += String.fromCharCode(digit.charCodeAt(i) - 1728)
            }
            return ret
        })
    })
}
```

this is the filter i want to test
does anyone know how to write this kind of test ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're writing `filters` used in multiple components, then it's quite easy to test.

Since `Vue.filter` simply takes a function, you can just write a test for the function independently of the filter by exporting the definition, like so:

```js
// Define the function independently and export it
export const englishNumber = function (value) {
  if (value === '۰') return 0
  if (!value) return ''
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    value = value.toString()
  }
  return value.replace(/[\u06F0-\u06F9]+/g, function (digit) {
    let ret = ''
    for (let i = 0, len = digit.length; i < len; i++) {
      ret += String.fromCharCode(digit.charCodeAt(i) - 1728)
    }
    return ret
  })
}

// Pass the function in to the filter defintion
Vue.filter('englishNumber', englishNumber)
```

Then in your test file, import the function and test it like you do anything else:

```js
import { englishNumber } from '#/lib/filters.js'

describe("englishNumber") { 
  it("does whatever") {
    expect(englishNumber("actual")).toEqual("expected")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can test filters with hand-made components. For example we have a filter that transform date into needed format:

```
// filters.js

import Vue from "vue";

Vue.filter("dateFormat", (incomingDate) => {
  // does the work here
}
```

So we can test it the following way:

```
// filters.spec.js

import Vue from "vue";
import "@/components/filters";
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";

const myComponent = Vue.component("myComponent", {
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date("January 1, 2020 01:10:30")
    };
  },
  template: "<p> {{ date | dateFormat }} </p>"
});

const localVue = createLocalVue();

describe("filter dateFormat", () => {
  it("filter transforms date to readable format", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(myComponent, {
      localVue
    });
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBe("<p> 01 January 2020 </p>");
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, this is the best way to test a filter. Testing the filter function itself is good, but I prefer your approach, more "in situation" :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to unit test a Vue filter would be to declare it locally inside your component (using Vue's API and Vue.filter).
You can then write unit tests inside your Vue component.
You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637254/vue-js-filters-and-testing)

Comment: This only works if the filter is used in one single component. If you're trying to share components, this would result in a bunch of unnecessarily repetitive code and tests.